# How do I only get the year?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, date

I have the following code:

```
string ship = "";

foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "not-annotated hover")
    {
        ship = el.InnerText;

        int startPos = ship.LastIndexOf("Ship date:") + "Ship date:".Length + 1;
        int length = ship.IndexOf("Country:") - startPos;
        string sub = ship.Substring(startPos, length);

        textBox3.Text = sub;
    }
```

This is to get a date into textBox3.

Let's say that the string `sub` is `May 19, 2013`, how do I get only the year of that string and take it into an int?

**NOTE:** The date always changes!

Comment: Is it always in the form "Month-name day, year"?

Comment: What is the general format of the date? If that is known, you can use DateTime.ParseExact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your extraction of the date part into `sub` is correct for all existing cases, you can then use `DateTime.Parse()` to parse the date into a `DateTime` and access the year:

```
int year = DateTime.Parse(sub).Year;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest convert it into `DateTime` and then look for `Year` Property. You could use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the date format.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sub, "MMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;

int year = dt.Year;    //2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Will two ways,

1. Either by casting `sub` to `datetime` and then get the year, that if you can cast this format `May 19, 2013`

   ```
   Convert.ToDateTime(sub).Year
   ```
2. or if not just split the string and get your value

   ```
   sub.Split(' ')[2]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

We can split a string by multiple character delimiter using String.split() method. You can split a string on a new line or carriage return using the delimiter "\r\n". You can retrieve the result of a String splt() method to a C# List.

*The following program convert the String Array to a List:*

```
string strDate = “26/07/2011”; //Format – dd/MM/yyyy
//split string date by separator, here I’m using ‘/’
string[] arrDate = strDate.Split(‘/’);
//now use array to get specific date object
string day = arrDate[0].ToString();
string month = arrDate[1].ToString();
string year = arrDate[2].ToString();
```

You can Split that string in "space" also let's try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sSource = el.InnerText; //el.InnerText something like "Ship date:May 19, 2013"
int i = sSource.Text.LastIndexOf("Ship date:") + ("Ship date:").Length;
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(sSource.Substring(i));
int year = date.Year;
textBox3.Text = year.ToString();
```

Comment: I have test to use May 19, 2013 format the code is works well